# Appgyver Steroids js Navbar update clashing with boilerplate angular method

Tags: javascript, steroids, appgyver, supersonic

I am writing a single page appgyver js application. When the application loads up (ondeviceready) it checks to see if a user is logged in via js and if so it fires a js method (Method 1). The js method does a few things, the last of which is to update the navbar title.

I am experiencing a problem whereby the boilerplate code in application.js

```
angular.module('SteroidsApplication', [
  'supersonic'
])
.controller('IndexController', function($scope, supersonic) {

  $scope.navbarTitle = "AppName";

});
```

seems to be running after Method 1 runs, despite being called in the head of the html file. Method 1 is within the body of index.html.

Method 1 does run, and the success handler of the supersonic.ui.navigationBar.update method is called. If I run method 1 after initial startup, the navbar update works as expected.

Does anyone know why the boilerplate method is running after Method 1, and how I can fix this?

### Edit 1

If I comment out

```
  $scope.navbarTitle = "AppName";
```

The same problem occurs.

### Edit 2

This is definitely a timing issue. If I delay Method 1 by 3 seconds (using setTimeout) the issue disappears. This doesn't fix the problem, but it does corroborate my initial suspicions.

Comment: Can you try your code wrapped in `supersonic.ui.views.current.whenVisible( function(){ // your code });`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did try this but it also didn't work. The only solution I've found is the setTimeout method :/

Comment: Did you ask your question [here](http://community.appgyver.com/) as well? There are a lot more developers looking at that forum for Appgyver related things.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I haven't asked there - I suspected SO would be a bit more active. I'll try there too :)